# Algorithm to extend to shortest palindrome by only adding characters at the end of the string

Tags: c++, algorithm

I found one algorithm problem. I solved that problem, but I want to optimize that. I ask the same problem here.

**Problem**

One String is given and the length of that string is **N <= 10000000**. All characters of that string is from **'a' to 'z'**. Now we have to calculate smallest palindrome that we can make from given string by adding characters the end.

**Example**

Given String = 'abab'

Output = 'ababa'

Reasoning:  the string `ababa` contains the string `abab` starting from both the beginning and end of the string, with only 1 extra character on each end.

**Edited**

String = 'abbcd'
Output = 'abbcdcbba'

**My attemp**

I can solve this problem in O(N^2) complexity.

**My question**

Can I solve this problem in less than O(N^2) time ? , If yes, than what is the algorithm? (Give me a hint)

Comment: The smallest palindrome is `a`. I think you mean the largest palindrome? And how can you make `ababa` from `abab`? Are you allowed to re-use letters? It's not completely clear...

Comment: Is the rule "your palindrome must use every letter in the string (including duplicates), and as many letters as needed to complete the palindrome. It is therefore always > N"?

Comment: What ?? Did you frame this question on your own ?

Comment: No, I found this on topcoder.

Comment: You're editing everything except the title, how come its the smallest ?

Comment: Sorry, My writing is not so good. It would be good, if you make me correct.

Comment: @G.Bach Then if given string is `bbccd` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in a palindrome, all pairs of characters with an equal distance to the middle of the string are equal.

This suggests the following algorithm:

> Find the largest palindromic suffix, then append the reverse of the substring to the left of this palindromic suffix. This will get you the shortest palindrome obtainable by adding characters to the end of the string.

A brute implementation of this will be `O(n^2)`. You can get `O(n)` by using two [rolling hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) to test if a suffix is a palindrome in `O(1)`.

Here's an outline of how these hashes work:

```
hForward(suff)  = suff[0] * p^0 + suff[1] * p^1 + ... + suff[k] * p^k
hBackward(suff) = suff[k] * p^0 + suff[k-1] * p^1 + ... + suff[0] * p^k

When adding a new character to the suffix:
Note that this is added to the beginning, since we should iterate the suffixes
from right to left.
hForward(c + suff) = c * p^0 + p * hForward(suff)
hBackward(c + suff) = hBackward(suff) + c * p^(k + 1)
```

Where `p` should probably be a (small-ish) prime and you should do all the computations mod another (large-ish) prime. In order to keep it efficient, compute the powers incrementally, don't use any exponentiation algorithm. You can use more hashes to avoid false positives.

If I'm not confusing things, there is also a solution involving the [KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), but I am not really familiar with it anymore.

Comment: @IVIad Now I totally understand. Thanks for the implementation that you edited in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward θ(n) approach (for an n-character input string S) is to build a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) T for S, in θ(n) time.  Let R=reverse(S). In time O(n), use T to find the longest match for R among suffixes of S.  Suppose the longest match has m characters; ie, the first m characters of R match the last m of S, and m is maximal.  Let P be the last n-m characters of R, or the reverse of the first n-m of S.  The desired result is S + P.