# Minimum number of characters to be inserted at the end of a string to make it a palindrome

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The question is like this--

We have to find the minimum number of characters to be inserted **at the end** of a string to make it a palindrome.

So, in my efforts to do this problem, I figured that this is equivalent to finding the largest palindromic substring which is also a suffix of the string.

I could do this in O(n^2) easily but I am looking for a O(n) solution which is probably possible using modified KMP. Somebody please help me figure out.

Comment: Shouldn't the "reverse" of the substring be same as the string's suffix?

Comment: @user1990169 Yes. I have made that edit.

Comment: There is a nice answer on Quora: http://www.quora.com/What-are-different-algorithms-for-converting-a-string-into-a-palindrome-by-adding-characters-to-the-end-other-than-appending-the-reverse-of-the-string-to-itself

Comment: @MiljenMikic Thanks, That was an awesome read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have an approach that uses hashing posted as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034211/algorithm-to-extend-to-shortest-palindrome-by-only-adding-characters-at-the-end/18034305#18034305).

You can indeed also use KMP. You can compute the [prefix function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792118/kmp-prefix-table) for the reversed string, and then iterate your initial string from left to right:

KMP computes a function `prefix[i] = longest prefix of the string that is a suffix of string[1..i]`

However, we want to know `the longest suffix of our string that is a prefix of the reversed string`. Why? If we have:

```
15232 => reverse = 23251
```

Then the longest suffix of the string that is a prefix of the reversed string is `232`. This is a palindrome, and it lets us find what you're asking because a suffix of the string overlaps a prefix of the reversed string if the two are palindromes.

You have the cases:

```
prefix[i] = length - i => you can get a palindrome of 
            length 2*prefix[i] centered at i and i+1

prefix[i] = length - i + 1 => you can get a palindrome of
            length 2*prefix[i] - 1 centered at i

prefix[i] < length - i => you can't have a palindrome, ignore this position
```

So it suffices to compute the prefix function of the KMP algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

A simple code to insert minimum number of characters and return them to make the given string a pallindrome

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
bool isPalin(char *s,int x,int l)
{
    for(int i=x,j=l-1;i<j;i++,j--)
        if(s[i]!=s[j])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
char * f(char *s)
{
    // if s is NULL return NULL
    if(!s)
        return NULL;
    int i,l,j;
    l=strlen(s);
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        // check if string is pallindrome from [i...l-1]
        if(isPalin(s,i,l) == 1)
            break;
    }
    // if s is already a pallindrome return NULL
    if(i==0)
        return NULL;
    int k=0;
    // make a char*
    char *ans = new char[i+1];
    for(i-=1;i>=0;i--)
        ans[k++]=s[i];
    ans[k++]='\0';
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    char *a = "wxytabbat";
    cout<<f(a)<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```